# Error when page loads, instead of after form submit?

Tags: javascript

When I open my local host, I am getting the following error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from //at getData ((index):60)`

Which is pointing to these lines of code

```
 const response = await fetch(url, {
```

&

```
getData(`/${url}`)
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error when I load the page, as should I only get something like this when I search for something?

This is the larger block of code I am referring to:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); getData(); })

const form = document.getElementById('Submit')
var formResult = new FormData(form);
const url = '/' + encodeURIComponent(formResult.get("search")); 

async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {
    
  const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });
    return response.json();
  }

  getData(`/${url}`)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

for clarity on backend:

```
app.get('/:url', async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.url);
  try {
    await whoisssubmit.init();
    const site = await whoisssubmit.open(decodeURIComponent(req.params.url));
    const data = await site.analyze();

    return res.status(200).json(data);

  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    return res.status(500).json({ message : "Oops." });
    
  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are calling `getData()` at the end of the snippet that you provided.

```js
// Add url
const url = 'urlToApi';

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); getData(url).then(response => console.log(response)); })    
async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {        
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest fixing then? Don't I need to also call the function>?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to do. If you don't need that data before `submit` event then just remove `getData(`/${url}`)` call. If you are asking if you need to call function after adding it to eventListener then you don't. You can start with adding `console.log` with response data inside `getData` and passing `url` parameter to `getData` inside eventListener.

Comment: I don't need any data until after submit. So just remove the getData(`/${url}`)? Can you provide an answer as to what you mean just to ensure I understand?